Using Symbolic Method to derive generating function for rooted trees using their line graph
It is well known that the line graph of any tree $T$ on $n$ vertices is a block graph of size $n-1$ where each vertex is contained in at most $2$ blocks.
If we now consider a rooted tree with root $r$, then there is a distinguished block $\mathcal{R}$ of size $\mathrm{deg}(r)$ which arises from the neighborhood relations of the said root $r$.
For rooted trees, the generating function can be derived by means of the symbolic method, using the notation from the book of Sedgewick, Flajolet, Analytic Combinatorics, p.71., applied to the family $\mathcal{H}$ of rooted unordered trees as
$$\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{Z}\times\mathrm{MSet}(\mathcal{H})$$
by pulling out the root in the term $\mathcal{Z}$ and conneting any multiset of rooted trees to it. This is all clear to me.
Now my question: Can this be derived also from the perspective of the block graphs which are the line graphs of trees? This correspondence is 1-to-1, so this should be possible. I know that this is somewhat not necessary, because the construction of the generating function is already clear by the typical construction as presented in the book, but it seems to be a nice exercise for which we already know the answer.
I thought of it in the following way. Consider the class of block graphs arising from line graphs of trees, which we denote by $\mathcal{B}$. Denote by $\mathcal{B}_{\geq 1}$ the subclass such that any block has at least one vertex which is contained in exactly one block. The cross product implies then joining by identifying one vertex from one graph with one vertex from a seconded graph if they are both contained in exactly one block in the respective graphs. This basically rephrases what is done for trees and joining trees by edges.
We write blocks of size 1 as $\mathcal{Z}$. This means, based on the distinguished block $\mathcal{R}$ of size $\mathrm{deg}(r)$ as introduced above, we can write
$$\mathcal{B}=\sum_{r\geq 0} \mathcal{Z}^r\times \mathrm{MSet}_{\leq r}(\mathcal{B}_{\geq 1})$$
where the restriction $\mathrm{MSet}_{\leq r}$ implies that at most $r$ blocks can be joined to a block of size $r$, represented by $\mathcal{Z}^r$. By the disjoint structure of the multi-sets we have
$$\mathrm{MSet}_{\leq r}=\sum_{l=0}^r \mathrm{MSet}_{l}$$
which leads by some formal rewriting of the series above to
$$\mathcal{B}=\sum_{l\geq 0} \sum_{r\geq l} \mathcal{Z}^r\times \mathrm{MSet}_{l}(\mathcal{B}_{\geq 1}).$$
Now I am stuck because I do not manage to translate this into anything further. The term $\sum_{r\geq l} \mathcal{Z}^r$ would in a real number case evaluate to $\dfrac{\mathcal{Z}^l}{1-Z}$ but in the context of classes, this seems strange. Could anyone help me out here? How could I proceed? Or is there another way to derive the generating function using this approach?
PS: This is not a homework exercise but an idea I had, while reading the book by Sedgewick and Flajolet.
